# Adding HTTP endpoint to a small python application

Tags: python, http, server

I am looking for a guidance on the best way of creating a small python application with embedded HTTP endpoints.

This application will perform periodic tasks of its own, however it should also accept external commands via HTTP requests.

I've checked some standard python HTTP servers like Flask, but they seem to be targeted for more complex web application and run the "application" as a plugin for a WSGI server. It feels that the application will be small enough that I'd prefer to avoid using some big framework. What's more important, Flask seems to be centered around "request-response" model, which is may be fine for a pure web server but does not suit well for my application (because http requests is only one of many inputs to it).

Should I just run http.server in a separate python thread or is there a better solution?

Comment: A few questions: is there any minimal performance requirement? Is it aimed for production or local project? Could you provide other examples of inputs to your application? How much of "lightweightness" is required in your project?

Comment: It is a dev tool, so there are no hard boundaries on performance, however I'd expect it to behave reasonably. After all, its just reading data from socket. Regarding degree of "lightweightness" - I'd like to avoid sticking to some huge framework like Django with all the bells and whistles. I'm looking for a rather simple solution for a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any concrete examples it's a bit hard to help.. but Flask is a microframework, so I doubt you'll find a lot smaller than that.

You can also check out FastAPI, which is built similar to Flask.

The main problem with your design is that the server acts both as the sender and the receiver of tasks, which eventually could cause you problems if something does not work.

**A better design is to have a server that listens on HTTP requests, and a scheduler service that issues HTTP requests to the server on periodic times - that way you could also construct tests for each of them separately as you decouple the "issuer" from the "executor" part of your system - and each of them can reside on a different system if needs be.**

Simplest solution might be:

- a simple python file running a FastAPI/Flask
- crontab job issuing requests

Comment: I think you have wrong impression that "the server acts both as the sender and the receiver of tasks". Some external commands (read webhooks) are called by 3rd party system and should be received by the server, and also may cause some long-time computation.